# Modifying parent element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have an navigation that uses unstyled list HTML element. My navigation can have a **depth of two levels**.

```
<ul class="nav">

  <li>
    <a href="#">depth-level-1 list item</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">depth-level-1 list item</a>
    <div class="subnav>
      <ul class="nav>
        <li>
          <a href="#">depth-level-2 list item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          ...
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    ...
  </li>

</ul>
```

What I want is when user hovers on a **depth-level-2** list item, the parent `li` should get `active` class.

By now I just wrote:

```
var s = $('.subnav');
s.mouseover(function() {
  s.parent('li').addClass('active');
}).mouseout(function(){
  s.parent('li').removeClass('active');
})
```

But this makes all **depth-level-1** list items `active` instead of making only the parent. Can you guys help me to solve that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer the hovered element instead of all subnavs (your `s` var, you should use `$(this)` instead):

```
s.mouseover(function() {
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).parent('li').removeClass('active');
})
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/5zBzX/

Comment: Thanks, it works! I knew that it will be sth with "this" but didn't knew how to do that.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help! Practically, you were referring to all the subnav items and their parents because `s` remained to be a set of all subnav elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var s = $('.subnav');
s.mouseover(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5zBzX/2/)

Comment: Is "closest" faster than "parent"?